# JS href onclick hide and show ul

Tags: javascript, hide, href, show

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="bottom-menu-active">    
    <li><a href="#">T1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T2</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="btn-up">направления</a>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$("#btn-up").click(function(){
$(this).next("#bottom-menu-active").toggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Here is my css:

```
#bottom-menu-active{
     display:none;
}
```

Why does my script not work?

Comment: There is no next element `bottom-menu-active` instead its previous. Use `prev('#bottom-menu-active').toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

As `ul` has `id` directly use ID selector. Also either use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to prevent default action

```
$("#btn-up").click(function(event){
   $("#bottom-menu-active").toggle();
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
   event.preventDefault();
});
```